# CROSSTAB with PIVOT

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

This is what my data looks like -

```
id  type  entity  diag  count
9   SER   ORG     a     18
9   SER   ORG     b     5
9   SER   PRAC    b     50
```

When I run this query -

```
select *
    FROM CROSSTAB($$
    SELECT
        id, type, entity,
        diag,
        count
    FROM calc
    $$, $$
    SELECT
       name
    FROM diagnosis
    ORDER by name
    LIMIT 3
$$) AS pivot (
    id INT,
    type  TEXT,
    entity INT, 
    a INT, b INT, c int
);
```

The output is -

```
id  type  entity  a  b
9   SER   ORG     18 5
```

What happened to the last record in the input?

I would expect this output -

```
id  type  entity  a  b
9   SER   ORG     18 5
9   SER   PRAC       50
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your `Crosstab` function in this way:

```
select 
col[1] "id", 
col[2] "Type", 
col[3] "Entity", 
a, 
b, 
c
    FROM CROSSTAB($$
    SELECT
        ARRAY[id::varchar, type, entity],
        diag,
        count
    FROM calc order by 1
    $$, $$
    SELECT
       name
    FROM diagnosis
    ORDER by name
    LIMIT 3
$$) AS pivot (
col text[], 
    a INT, b INT, c int
);
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9e8c8660abfa0254bcb68618484787a8)